# Make Text.Parsec.Indent parsing fail if unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: haskell, indentation, parsec

I am trying to parse a string in Haskell which represents a tree. Each node is on a line, where the indentation determines the nesting (e.g. like the syntax of Python or Haskell).

A successful parsing result should be of the type `[Tree]` (a forest of rose trees), where

```
data Tree = Tree String [Tree]
          deriving Show
```

For example, the string

```
A
    B
    C
D
    E
        F
```

should result in

```
[Tree "A" [Tree "B" [], Tree "C" []], Tree "D" [Tree "E" [Tree "F" []]]]
```

With the [Haskell indents package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/indents) and the help of an [article about how to parse indented trees](http://changaco.oy.lc/blog/parse-indented-tree/), I could parse examples like this.

The problem is that my current implementation successfully parses the string

```
A
    B
        C
      D
```

as

```
[Tree "A" [Tree "B" [Tree "C" []]], Tree "D" []]
```

The node `D` is parsed as another root. However, I would like to make the parsing fail, since `D` is unindented relative to `C`, but it does not match the indentation level of `A` or `B`.

My implementation is as follows (simplifications: tree labels are nonempty and have alphanumeric characters only; not every kind of Unicode newline is supported).

```
import qualified Control.Applicative as A
import qualified Control.Monad as M
import qualified Text.Parsec as P
import qualified Text.Parsec.Indent as I

parse :: String -> Either P.ParseError [Tree]
parse = I.runIndent "" . P.runParserT forest () ""

forest = P.many tree A.<* P.eof

tree = spacing A.*> I.withBlock Tree node tree

spacing = P.many P.newline A.*> indentation

indentation = P.many $ P.char ' '

node = label A.<* spacing

label = P.many1 P.alphaNum A.<* lineEnd

lineEnd = M.void P.newline P.<|> P.eof
```

How can this parser be changed to accept only unindents which match some outer indentation level? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't `same` provide this already?

Comment: I think I got it now. Defining `forest = I.block tree A.<* P.eof` instead helps! (I need to wait a little to answer myself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replacing the definition of `forest` by

```
forest = I.block tree A.<* P.eof
```

seems to do the trick. `I.block` here makes sure that the roots of the source string are indented to the same level.

The example

```
A
    B
        C
      D
```

now fails with

```
(line 4, column 7):
unexpected 'D'
expecting " " or end of input
not indented or indentation doesn't match
```

The problem with `P.many tree` is that a `tree` can be arbitrarily indented. As soon as an unindentation of a `tree` does not match any outer indentation level (`D` in the example), the parser happily grows another top-level `tree` (root) of the `forest` instead of failing.